# how to filter documents from populate in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, join, mongodb-query, mongoose-populate

I have booking schema with ref state and city. I want to get only documents from only specific pair of city,state( but only names of city, state is given)

```
const bookingSchema = new Schema({
    id: {
        type: String
    },
    service: {
        type: String
    },
    city: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'City'
    }, 
    state: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'State',
        
    }
})


const stateSchema=new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    }
})


const citySchema=new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    }
})
```

I need output (documents) containing *id* and *service* from `bookingSchema`, but only those documents (can be more than one) with a certain city name (for example `name="New York"`)

In SQL it can be done by query :

```sql
SELECT * FROM bookings bk
   INNER JOIN city ct ON bk.city_id=ct.id
   INNER JOIN state st ON bk.state_id=st.id
   WHERE ct.name='city name' AND st.name='state name'
```

I also did use [`populate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) with match, but the problem is that it doesn't filter bookingSchema, but it actually work in way that it only populate that field who has state name that is given and for other documents it gives null.

PLEASE TELL ME HOW TO FILTER DOCUMENTS BASED ON REF

Comment: please provide sample data of city and state and your prefer output

Comment: const stateSchema=new Schema({
  
    name: {
        type: String
    }
})


const citySchema=new Schema({
  
    name: {
        type: String
    }
})
I need output (documents) containing :
 id and service from bookingSchema
,but only those documents(can be more than one) which has city name= (for example "New York")

Answer (score 0):

use aggregate on booking collection like this

- lookup : lookup city from city collection
- lookup : lookup state from state collection
- unwind : destruct array of city
- unwind : destruct array of state
- project : create final result

example  : https://mongoplayground.net/p/hGQFhkoujsC

```
db.booking.aggregate([
      {
        "$lookup": {
          "from": "city",
          "localField": "city",
          "foreignField": "_id",
          "as": "city"
        }
      },
      {
        "$lookup": {
          "from": "state",
          "localField": "state",
          "foreignField": "_id",
          "as": "state"
        }
      },
      {
        "$unwind": "$city"
      },
      {
        "$unwind": "$state"
      },
      {
        "$match": {
          "city.name": "New York",
          "state.name": "Test State"
        }
      },
      {
        "$project": {
          _id: 1,
          city: "$city.name",
          service: 1,
          state: "$state.name"
        }
      }
    ])
```